# Objective-C - How to open a .csv file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am all new on programming. Unfortunately I have no experience in C or Objective-C. My question is quite simple.

How could I open with MS Excel a .csv file from the open panel ?
How could I export a .csv file into a database ?

Thank you for your time and your help.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end
@implementation AppDelegate
- (IBAction)Browse:(id)sender {
    {
     NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

     [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"csv", nil]];
        // Permet seulement d'ouvrir un fichier .csv
     [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
     [openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bureau"]]];
        // Ouvre le répertoire Bureau en automatique

        if([openPanel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile: 
            withApplication:@"Microsoft Excel"];
            NSLog(@"Fichier ouvert : %@", [openPanel URL]);
        }
    }
@end
```

Comment: Your code shows an attempt to use excel to open a file. I assume that you want to open the file to process it you should pass the URL for the selected file to another method for processing. While you are learning how to process the file you should skip the open panel completely and just hard code a URL to your test file. Start with that as a simpler program to get started.

Comment: Hello Mr. Elemans, I have tried to hard code the URL. It does work. But I wanted to open first the .csv file in MS Excel to check the file is OK, without code any time the URL of each file. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet. Remember that you may need to handle each column as a row value.

```
NSMutableArray *colA = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *colB = [NSMutableArray array];

NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"microsoft-excel.csv"];

NSArray* rows = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (NSString *row in rows){
     NSArray* columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
     [colA addObject:columns[0]];
     [colB addObject:columns[1]];
}
```